# Nginx rewrite not working on different locations

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, location

i have a problem that i can't figure it out,

so my problem is this, i am trying to locate diferent rewrite rules on a subfolder which is the mobile version. site.com is the main site and site.com/mobile/ is the mobile site, what i want to do is to add different rewrite to both locations, is this possible?

```
server {
listen      111.111.111:80;
server_name site.com www.site.com;
index       index.php index.html index.htm;
root        /home/admin/web/site.com/public_html;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/site.com.log combined;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/site.com.bytes bytes;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/site.com.error.log error;
location / {

rewrite ^/index.html$ / permanent;
rewrite ^/([^/]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /watch.php?vid=$2;
rewrite ^/([^/]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+).html$ /watch.php?vid=$2;
rewrite ^/fpembed-(.*).swf$ /fpembed.php?vid=$1;
rewrite ^/uploads/thumbs/(.*)-social.(jpg|gif|png)$ /social-thumb.php?vid=$1;
rewrite ^/rss.xml$ /rss.php last;

 location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
        expires     max;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return  404;
        }

        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9002;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}

location /mobile/ {
alias /home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/mobile/;

rewrite ^/index.html$ / permanent;
rewrite ^/category.html$ /category.php;
rewrite ^/([^/]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+).html$ /watch.php?vid=$2;
rewrite ^/fpembed-(.*).swf$ /fpembed.php?vid=$1;
rewrite ^/rss.xml$ /rss.php last;          

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
        expires     max;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return  404;
        }

        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9002;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

can someoane tell me what i'm doing wrong here? Thanks a lot

Comment: So nobody can help me with this?

Comment: Your mobile rewrites are all wrong. If you are going to use the `^` anchor, you need to include the `/mobile` prefix too. Like `rewrite ^/mobile/index.html$ /mobile/ permanent;`

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks man, this solved my problem :)